# Convert nullable bool? to bool

Tags: c#, nullable

How do you convert a nullable `bool?` to `bool` in C#?

I have tried `x.Value` or `x.HasValue` ...

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You ultimately have to decide what the null bool will represent.  If `null` should be `false`, you can do this:

```
bool newBool = x.HasValue ? x.Value : false;
```

Or:

```
bool newBool = x.HasValue && x.Value;
```

Or:

```
bool newBool = x ?? false;
```

Comment: What about in `VB.NET` if you do: `dim newBool as Boolean = CBool(x)`?
Will `null` be converted to `false` or will a exception be thrown?

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: Yes it does - It was suggested in a 'Quick Action' for a `Linq` statement 'Where' clause, I couldn't understand why `lifted operators` didn't seem to work inside Linq (perhaps it's just VB.NET?) - I have just tested and it does throw an invalid cast exception

Comment: Or: bool newBool = x == true;

Answer (score 129):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx): `x ?? something`, where `something` is a boolean value that you want to use if `x` is `null`.

Example:

```
bool? myBool = null;
bool newBool = myBool ?? false;
```

`newBool` will be false.

Comment: So, `bool? myBool = null;  bool newBool = myBool ?? false;`

Answer (score 96):

You can use `Nullable{T}` `GetValueOrDefault()` method. This will return false if null.

```
 bool? nullableBool = null;

 bool actualBool = nullableBool.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think this is the best hybrid between conciseness and C# noob-friendliness. Also note that there is an overload where you can specify the default value.

Comment: I like using this method, because it can create 'elegant' if statements `if (nullableBool.GetValueOrDefault())`

Answer (score 11):

If you're going to use the `bool?` in an `if` statement, I find the easiest thing to do is to compare against either `true` or `false`.

```
bool? b = ...;

if (b == true) { Debug.WriteLine("true"; }
if (b == false) { Debug.WriteLine("false"; }
if (b != true) { Debug.WriteLine("false or null"; }
if (b != false) { Debug.WriteLine("true or null"; }
```

Of course, you can also compare against null as well.

```
bool? b = ...;

if (b == null) { Debug.WriteLine("null"; }
if (b != null) { Debug.WriteLine("true or false"; }
if (b.HasValue) { Debug.WriteLine("true or false"; }
//HasValue and != null will ALWAYS return the same value, so use whatever you like.
```

If you're going to convert it to a bool to pass on to other parts of the application, then the Null Coalesce operator is what you want.

```
bool? b = ...;
bool b2 = b ?? true; // null becomes true
b2 = b ?? false; // null becomes false
```

If you've already checked for null, and you just want the value, then access the Value property.

```
bool? b = ...;
if(b == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
else
    SomeFunc(b.Value);
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use the null coalescing operator: `??`

```
bool? x = ...;
if (x ?? true) { 

}
```

The `??` with nullable values works by examining the provided nullable expression.  If the nullable expression has a value the it's value will be used else it will use the expression on the right of `??`

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for the use case when you simply want to test the `bool?` in a condition. It can also be used to get a normal `bool`. It is an alternative I personnaly find easier to read than the `coalescing operator ??`.

If you want to test a condition, you can use this

```
bool? nullableBool = someFunction();
if(nullableBool == true)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

The above if will be true only if the `bool?` is true.

You can also use this to assign a regular `bool` from a `bool?`

```
bool? nullableBool = someFunction();
bool regularBool = nullableBool == true;
```

witch is the same as

```
bool? nullableBool = someFunction();
bool regularBool = nullableBool ?? false;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
bool? a = null;
bool b = Convert.toBoolean(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if (bn.HasValue)
{
  b = bn.Value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The complete way would be:

```
bool b1;
bool? b2 = ???;
if (b2.HasValue)
   b1 = b2.Value;
```

Or you can test for specific values using

```
bool b3 = (b2 == true); // b2 is true, not false or null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting variation on the theme. At first and second glances you would assume the true branch is taken. Not so!

```
bool? flag = null;
if (!flag ?? true)
{
    // false branch
}
else
{
    // true branch
}
```

The way to get what you want is to do this:

```
if (!(flag ?? true))
{
    // false branch
}
else
{
    // true branch
}
```