# Cannot Convert bool? to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

My code in my Data Layer  *DtbseDropDown = ii.DtbseDropDown* is throwing an error and I am not sure how to get around it. The error says: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Here are the code blocks for my Data Layer and my Entities

**Data Layer**

```
public static List<ListProjectTypes> GetListProjectTypes()

    {
        using (var context = new Sys.EntityModels.HousingRehabEntities())
        {
            // build and execute query against the db
            //return context.ListProjectTypes.Where(x => x.DtbseDropDown=true).ToList();

            // build and execute query against the db
            return (from ii in context.ListProjectTypes
                    where (ii.DtbseDropDown == true)
                    //&& ((ii.LastName + ii.FirstName + ii.Middle) != null))
                    ////&& ((ii.LastName) != null))
                    orderby ii.SortOrder
                    select new Sys.Entities.ListProjectTypes
                    {
                        ProjectType = ii.ProjectType,
                        SortOrder = ii.SortOrder,
                        DtbseDropDown = ii.DtbseDropDown


        }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

**Entities**

```
namespace CityOfMesa.HousingRehab.Sys.Entities
{

 public class ListProjectTypes
    {
        public string ProjectType { get; set; }
        public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
        public bool DtbseDropDown { get; set; }
    public ListProjectTypes()
    {

        ProjectType = string.Empty;
        SortOrder = 0;
        DtbseDropDown = true;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert nullable bool? to bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075726/convert-nullable-bool-to-bool)

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's cause your datamodel `ii.DtbseDropDown` is a nullable bool and thus the error. You should try change it to

```
public class ListProjectTypes
    {
        public string ProjectType { get; set; }
        public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
        public bool? DtbseDropDown { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`DtbseDropDown` property is `bool` (can have `true` or `false` values) whereas `ii.DtbseDropDown` is `bool?` (shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`, i.e. can also be `null`. See [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.140).aspx) for more). You're trying to assign a `bool?` to a `bool`, hence the error you are getting. What you need to do is check if the `bool?` struct actually has a value first. If it does ([`.HasValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx)), return the actual value ([`.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx)), else return a default value (I've set the default value to `false` here):

```
DtbseDropDown = ii.DtbseDropDown.HasValue ? ii.DtbseDropDown.Value : false
```

You can also use `ii.DtbseDropDown.GetValueOrDefault()`, as suggested by [@test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515659/cannot-convert-bool-to-bool#comment64428408_38515861) in the comments. The difference between the two is that with my approach you can control what value to output when `ii.DtbseDropDown` is `null`, whereas [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `default(bool)` (i.e. `false`) by default.

Comment: `ii.DtbseDropDown.GetValueOrDefault()` seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Indeed, just being more explicit so the OP can see how the values are being set. I'll edit your solution in too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use null-coalescing operator.

```
bool? myBool = null;
bool newBool = myBool ?? false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `DtbseDropDown = ii.DtbseDropDown` to `DtbseDropDown = (bool)ii.DtbseDropDown`